# Show that if $F_{U|W}( aw|w)=\frac{1}{2}$ then $U$ is gaussian; assume $W=U+Z$ where $Z$ is standard normal

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Let
\begin{align}
W=U+Z
\end{align}
where $Z$ is a standard normal and independent of random variable $U$.  Suppose that for some given $a \in (0,1)$
\begin{align}
F_{U|W}(aw|w)=\frac{1}{2}, \forall w\in \mathbb{R}. 
\end{align}
where $F_{U|W}(u|w)$ is the conditional cdf of $U$ given $W$, that is
\begin{align}
F_{U|W}(u|w)=P( U \le u| W=w)
\end{align}
**Question:** Show that the above holds if and only if $U$ is Gaussian.  (Assume $U$ is zero mean)

**Forward direction:**
One of the directions is easy if $U$ is Gaussian, since the sum is Guassian we have that
\begin{align}
F_{U|W}(t|w)=\Phi \left( \frac{t- E[U|W=w]}{\sqrt{Var(U|W=w)}}\right)=\Phi \left( \frac{t- b w}{\sqrt{b}} \right)
\end{align}
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the cdf of standard normal and we have used that $E[U|W=w]=bw$ and $\frac{E[U^2]}{E[U^2]+1}=Var(U|W=w)=b$.

Therefore, the condition reduces to
\begin{align}
\Phi \left( \frac{aw- b w}{\sqrt{b}} \right)=\frac{1}{2}, \forall w\in \mathbb{R}. 
\end{align}
which is equivalent to
\begin{align}
 aw- b w =0, \forall w\in \mathbb{R},
\end{align}

Therefore, if we choose $U$ to be Gaussian such that $a=b=\frac{E[U^2]}{E[U^2]+1}$, it will match the desired equation.

The question now is how to show that Gaussian is the only one that satisfies this.

Comment: What does the notation "$F_{U|W}(aw|w)$" mean?  Is $F_{U|W}(aw|w)=\mathbb{P}(U \le aw | W=w)$ (up to some technicalities about conditioning on events of probability zero), or something different?

Comment: @Thanks. $F_{U|W}(u|w)$ is the conditional cdf of $U$ given $W$ so it is $P(U\le u| W=w)$. I will add this.